# How to check if input command put into readarray did not fail?

Tags: bash

I'm using readarray to read the result of a SQL query into an array.
I'm probably missing something obvious, but how can I ensure that my SQL query did not fail ?

(I'm using readarray at other place with other command so I'm looking for a generic solution)

```
query="SELECT unknow_column FROM unknow_table;" # That will fail
readarray -t queryResultList < <(echo "$query" | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -N)
echo "$?" # always show 0
```

Comment: You are testing the status code of `readarray` and not the one of `mysql`. AFIK, if you are using process substitution, you can not retrieve the status code from this process directly. My suggestion: Either do not use process substitution, or write a complete script for the `mysql` process, which retrieves the status code and writes it to a file (and then read this file from your main script).

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, too bad, I assumed there was a way. I'm thinking about setting an env var in order to detect failure or not.

Comment: The problem is that the substituted process (logically) must run as a child process, so this precludes the use of an environment variable. BTW, the invocation is written simpler as `mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -N <<<$query`; no need to use a pipe here.

Comment: @user1934428 Damn, I didn't think enough ... Thanks for the invocation tip. I still need to use readarray in order to have every sql result line into an array. Then maybe the creation of a file into /tmp but this seem very unreliable to me.

Comment: If the query output is plain text (i.e. no null bytes or anything like that), you could store it in a variable instead, like `result=$(mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -N <<<"$query")` (BTW, I recommend double-quoting the here-string, because some bash versions had a weird parsing bug if it wasn't quoted).

Comment: @Tom's: Why is a temporary file **unreliable**? Unconvenient maybe, but unless you do it badly (i.e. using a fixed filename for instance), it should not be unreliable. Aside from this, I find the suggestion by GordonDavisson worth considering. Another - less elegant - possibility is to exploit the fact that, if mysql fails, the output will most likely be empty. Hence if  `queryResultList` is empty, you can conclude that there was an error. This assumes that `mysql` writes error messages to stderr (I believe it does; it has been ages since I had used it).